# Clear Kubernetes persistent volume on new image

Tags: wordpress, docker, kubernetes, gitlab

I have a deployment of wordpress with a custom docker image with a custom theme copied into the image that gets deployed into a kubernetes cluster with a persistent volume.

The initial deployment works great and the website presents as expected. The problem comes when I update the theme and deploy a new docker image, because of the persistent volume the theme files don't seem to be updated to the new version of the theme in the docker image.

Is there a to clear/reset the wp-content/themes/my-theme directory when I deploy the new image?

Any help is appreciated and code samples below.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM wordpress:latest
COPY ./my-thtme /usr/src/wordpress/wp-content/themes/my-theme
```

Persistent Volume Claim:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: wordpress
spec:
    accessModes:
        - ReadWriteMany
    resources:
        requests:
            storage: 2Gi
    storageClass: "nfs"
```

Deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: wordpress
spec:
  replicas: 2
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 0
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: wordpress
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: wordpress
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: gitlab-auth
      containers:
        - name: wordpress
          image: registry.gitlab.com/user/wordpress:1234
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          env:
            - name: WORDPRESS_DB_HOST
              value: wordpress-mysql
            - name: WORDPRESS_DB_USER
              value: mysql_wordpress
            - name: WORDPRESS_DB_NAME
              value: wordpress
            - name: WORDPRESS_DB_TABLE_PREFIX
              value: _wp
            - name: WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: mysql-pass
                  key: mysql-password
          volumeMounts:
          - name: wordpress-data
            mountPath: /var/www/html/wp-content
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 80
              protocol: TCP
      volumes:
      - name: wordpress-data
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: wordpress
```

Comment: Kubernetes won't do anything to the content of volumes; if you want some particular behavior on upgrade, you need to implement it yourself in the container code.

Comment: Can use an [`initContainer`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/) to purge the files from your persistent volume if they exist before the app containers in the [Pod](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/) are started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is more than one way to do it. You could add an [`initContainer`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/) to the [`Deployment`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/) spec to remove existing files from the [`Persistent Volume`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/) before app containers in the [`Pod`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/) are started. For example:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: wordpress
spec:
  replicas: 2
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 0
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: wordpress
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: wordpress
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: gitlab-auth
      initContainers:
      - name: init-theme
        image: "alpine:3"
        command: ["sh", "-c", "if [ -d /var/www/html/wp-content/my-theme ]; then rm -rf /var/www/html/wp-content/my-theme; fi"]
        volumeMounts:
          - name: workdpress-data
            mountPath: /var/www/html/wp-content
      containers:
      ...
      volumes:
      - name: wordpress-data
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: wordpress
```

Comment: This is half way to a realistic solution. My problem with it is that is executes on every replication of the application. For example if we went from 1 pod to 3 it would run init containers on every pod init which is not desirable.

Looking into possibly doing this as a job with the deployment update to purge the theme from volumes before deploying the new image.